# Spring Security + Keycloak - setting no bearer token to REST request leads to an response with HTML content

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, bearer-token

I'm using a SpringBoot 2 (2.7.0) application (including Spring security 5.7.1) to secure REST endpoints with Keycloak for authentication and authorization. Everything works fine but the only thing which bothers me is when I don't set the bearer token I get a HTTP 400 response. The response itself is correct but the body of the response contains HTML (Keycloak login page).

Is there a way to avoid that the body of the response contains the login page? I would like to set a custom response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an expected default behavior. If you want to instead get relevant 4xx error instead, you can try setting the the "bearer-only" in your "keycloak.json" file so that it would not redirect API calls (i.e. AJAX calls from browser) to the login page:

```json
{
  ...
  "bearer-only": true
}
```